# How to upgrade the third party “executable packages” automatically in a “WIX Burn Bootstrapper”

Tags: wix, components, upgrade

**Background**
WiX Installer technology is completely new to me.

In my production, I used an EXE installer (created by WiX) to install my software. There is a third-party "executable packages"(with V5 version) including in the installer.
The third-party "executable packages" should be upgraded to V6 version in next release of my software.
So my question is... how could I configure the Wix installer to check whether the old version of that third-party "executable packages" has been installed in the target computer or not. And how could it be uninstalled before the newer version is installed automatically in the Wix installer?

The installation configuration of the third-party "executable packages" is as below now.

```
<ExePackage
      Name="Fingerprint Driver"
      DisplayName="Fingerprint Driver"
      SourceFile="..\..\common\prereq-packages\FingerprintDriver_64-bit_5.10.32.exe"
      Cache="no"
      PerMachine="yes"
      Permanent="yes"
      Vital="yes"
      InstallCommand="/s /v&quot;/qb&quot;"
           UninstallCommand="/x /s /v&quot;/qb&quot;"
      Compressed="yes"
      DetectCondition="Fingerprint"
      Description="[Dependency::MyProduction][UpgradeByUninstallInstall][IsTypicalInstall]"
      SuppressSignatureVerification="yes">
        <dep:Provides Key="Fingerprint" Version="5.10.32.0" />
      </ExePackage>
```

Comment: I would rephrase the question, replacing 'components' (a term used a lot elsewhere in the WiX world) with 'executable packages' and 'WIX installer' (a term used to represent an MSI built with WiX) with 'WIX Burn Bootstrapper'. This might help get the right attention to your problem.

Comment: So, moving forward with this question, and assuming my answer is not enough to guide you to a solution, could you add more context to your post, more source code for your bundle, information about your driver that you are trying to install, etc., so that I can attempt to provide you a more complete solution? Generally, the less context you give, the more of a general 'suggestion' you will get as an answer. For more complete answers you will need to provide a more complete question.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like the `exe` installer you are trying to use does not support a `RepairCommand`, based on your example.

One thing you try to do is incorporate the `InstallCondition` attribute on your `ExePackage` element. From the WiX Toolset doc:

> A condition to evaluate before installing the package. The package will only be installed if the condition evaluates to true. If the condition evaluates to false and the bundle is being installed, repaired, or modified, the package will be uninstalled.

That being said, I think this would require 2 `ExePackage` elements, one after the other in the chain. The first would be setup so that, if the `DetectCondition` evaluates to `true` (meaning the product is detected as installed on the system) but the `InstallCondition` evaluates to `false` (meaning the version that was detected is below the latest version that you would like to have installed), then the `UninstallCommand` will be executed. The second `ExePackage` element would need a `DetectCondition` that only evaluates to `true` if the target version of the product is installed, and you could omit the `InstallCondition` since we wouldn't want the newest version to ever uninstall in this scenario.

All of this is going to require accurate retrieval of the current installed version of the package, as well as correct version comparison conditions in the `DetectCondition` and `InstallCondition`. I can't give advice in that regard, since your example does not let me know how the `Fingerprint` variable is populated.